# Steps to update ADFS service account

Tags: adfs

Due to bad implementation we require to update ADFS (4.0) service account in Windows 2016.

Please specify steps or refer documentation or link to update ADFS service account. Looking for steps to update this manually.

Thanks in advance !

Regards,
Vinod Joshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check this Github [module](https://github.com/Microsoft/adfsToolbox/tree/master/serviceAccountModule) to change the service account for ADFS 2016.

Before that is done, it is best practice to take a back-up of the servers, by using this adfs [rapid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/ad-fs-rapid-restore-tool) restore tool.

Comment: Thanks for the response !

Both approaches(new installation and update existing ADFS) had given to client.

Am accepting you answer, Thanks again !